# How do I set a default image to a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a PNG image (in my database) that I want to load into my page in my canvas. I have no idea how to do it. I couldn't figure out how to load the image as a ImageBitmap or anything compatible with canvas. How do I give canvas the bytes and tell it that it's using the png format/set the mime to png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split this into two parts: (1) You'll want to load an image into something an ImageBitmap can use, and (2) you'll want to create the ImageBitmap to put this into your canvas.

This could look something like this:

```
const fileName = 'resources/image.png';
const fetched = await fetch(fileName); // Retrieve an image file.
const blob = await fetched.blob(); // Get a blob to represent this image.

const imageBitmap = await createImageBitmap(blob); // Create an imageBitmap from this blob.
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); // Make sure your HTML contains a <canvas> element.
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.drawImage(imageBitmap, 0,0); // Draw this image onto the canvas.
```

Comment: Strange. I got  the error "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable" but I think this is the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

## HTML

```
<img id="myImage" src="imageSrc">
<canvas id ="myCanvas" width="width" height="height"></canvas>
```

## JS

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("myImage");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

This is the simplest way. The `drawImage()` method can take multiple image sources, not just an HTML image element. For example, you do not need to put the image in the DOM as I demonstrated. I recommend you read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage